# geometric meaning of Ricci-flatness

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

What is the geometric meaning of Ricci-flatness? We know that if the Riemann tensor at a point vanished, manifold is flat at this point. but I don't know When the Ricci tensor vanished at a point, what is shape of manifold at this point? and a same question about scalar curvature.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339057/geometric-meaning-of-ricci-flatness?noredirect=1#comment731170_339057 ... I suggest making an edit to your post on the other site, so that you can receive better help.

Answer (score 1):

You find in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature):

- "Indeed, if $\xi$ is a vector of unit length on a Riemannian n-manifold, then $Ric(\xi,\xi)$ 
  is precisely (n−1) times the average value of the sectional curvature, taken over all the 2-planes containing $\xi$."
- In Riemann normal coordinates, the Taylor expansion of the Riemannian volume has vanishing first order term, and the second order term is $1/6$ times the Ricci curvature.